# WooCommerce - How to show specific category first-rest of products-specific category last

Tags: categories, loop, woocommerce-offtopic, order

This is the case:

- A product has 2 categories: "New products" and "Shirts"
- Another product has 2 categories: "Shirts" and "Outlet"

What I need is to show in a paginated loop the products with the following order:

- 1. Products with the category "New products"
- 2. Products with the category "Shirts"
- 3. Produts with the category "Outlet"

The category "Shirts" it's just an example. The problem is how to show first products which have the category "New products", later the rest of products in category, and finally the products which have the category "Outlet".

Is this possible?